# Open Android SDK Manager Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, android-sdk-2.3

How can I open the Android SDK Manager in the last Visual studio to update the android sdk version?

I know it's a simple question, but I did not find documentation about how to do it or the access to open the manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed Xamarin, so Android SDK manager can be opened in Visual Studio from
`Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager`

Answer (score 2):

You just run it directly off your hardrive.
It can be found here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: What I'm saying is, Febins solution and the option to Run SDK Manager wasn't in the Tools box. So if you just run the SDK Manager.exe directly, you should be able to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> Tools->Options...->Projects and Solutions->Java & Android->SDK Paths

[Source](https://docs.elementscompiler.com/VisualStudio/Setup/AndroidSDK/)

Hope it helps

Febin