# Android SDK could not be found - Android SDK Location is correct

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, android-sdk-2.3

I've installed Xamarin and tried in Visual Studio to start with a small app and test the web view with this. So for this, I've installed the JDK, the Android SDK and Android NDK on my computer. I'm working throught a tutorial for a web view and I have the problem, when I run the `Main.axml`, it shows me the error, that my Android SDK could not be found (look at the first attachement). When I check my location paths for the JDK, SDK and NDK, it shows me the correct path and a green tick, so the path and files are correct (look at the second attachement). But my app don't recognize it. What's the problem here? I found some threads on stackoverflow for the same problem, but nothing helped me.

**1. Attachement**

[image]

**2. Attachement**

[image]

- **OS:** Windows 8.1
- **IDE**: MS Visual Studio 14.0.23
- **Xamarin:** 4.2.0

**EDIT:**

I also tried to open my Android SDK Manager, but this one is disabled in my visual studio. I've installed Xamarin, so it should work:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It says that a *valid* Android SDK couldn't be found. As the message says, did you also install the required platform-tools?

Comment: @Lennart I just installed the Xamarin from their website and after this de JDK, SDK and NDK... Is there more to install? Thanks

Comment: I haven't used the SDK in a long time, but I remember that you also have to download the files for a specific Android version. There is an Android SDK manager that handles this, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262529/open-android-sdk-manager-visual-studio-2015

Comment: @Lennart I've also installed xamarin like in your link described, but my Android SDK Manager is disabled in my Visual Studio?! I can't open it (look at my edit...) Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried running the manager directly (second answer in my link)? Maybe VS disables the menu option because it also thinks that there is no SDK at all.

Comment: @Lennart I've opened the SDK Manager, installed the newest packages and tools and started the visual studio again - same problem... My mind is blowing...

Comment: Is Xamarin up to date? Why don't to try to update it? You could trigger a version check from Xamarin->Other options page.

Comment: @Kalitsov Hi, yes it should be up to date, I installed it directly from their website... Seems to be alright...

Comment: Please try to trigger the update as i explained. Xamarin (Microsoft) often do   new releases with a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: @Kalitsov Ok, I'll try it and inform you if it changed something

Comment: @Kalitsov Now I have another error. It says, my Android SDK Tools must be version 25.1.3 or newer, but wenn I open de Android SDK Manager, my installed version is 25.2.2 (so it's newer for sure than the error says). I have no ideas... But anyway thanks.

Comment: @Kalitsov Now it works. I reinstalled my android studio / android sdk and my xamarin. After that, I installed first the android studio and it's sdk. Than again the xamarin without the sdk. I also had to install the newest version of jdk and not the jdk which is installed with the xamarin. So now I had the newest sdk and jdk and the newest xamarin. In my visual studio I opened Tool - Options - Xamarin - Android seetings and set the paths for sdk, jdk and ndk to the newest versions. Than I checked if my sdk manager was enabled - it was and so I installed the sdk tools, start the app and it works

Comment: For me the most stable way is to use the Visual Studio installer. It installs the correct sdk, ndk and jdk. Later you can retarget if you want e.g. jdk 8. I have done this a number of times successfully. The best part is that you found a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried so many things and finally I have the solution for my problem:

**Possible reason for the problem:** I just installed the Xamarin, which installes also the JDK, Android SKD and Android NDK in it's wizzard, so I thought this should be the correct versions. After installing Xamarin, I opened my Visual Studio and checked the paths (Tool - Options - Xamarin - Android seetings) for my JDK, SDK and NDK. The paths show on the versions, which were installed by Xamarin. My Android SDK Manager was disabled.

**Solution:** Then I uninstall everything - the JDK, SDK and NDK and also the whole Xamarin and my old Android Studio. After that, I decided to install the newest JDK from the Java website, the newes Android SDK/NDK from the Android Studio website and a plane xamarin without the sdk/jdk installation. So I could be sure, that I have the correct versions. After the installation, I again opened Visual Studio - Tool - Options - Android seetings and set the paths to the new versions. Than I checked my Android SDK Manager and it was finally enabled and so I installed also the newest Android SDK Tools. After that I cleaned and builded my solution, start it and my android emulator opens my webview page. So I think, the best way is to install the required programms from their website and not automaticlly with xamarin. Now it works. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: do nearly the same. Install studio (android version) and android sdk tools pack, uninstall visual studio 2017 and install it back. correct SDK is now recognize and build seems ok. (Android studio is maybe not mandatory with the tools pack installation )